# How can I expand a relative path to full path for cxx_builtin_include_directories in cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info in bazel?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

When declaring a cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info and provide `cxx_builtin_include_directories`, I found the need to fully specify a include path. I only know the relative path of the directory in the crosstool.bzl file in `def _impl(ctx)`, how can I expand that fully?
For example

```
def _impl(ctx):
    cxx_builtin_include_directories = ["relative/clang/include"]
    return cc_common.create_cc_toolchain_config_info(
        ctx = ctx,
        features = features,
        tool_paths = tool_paths,
        cxx_builtin_include_directories = cxx_builtin_include_directories,
        # ...
    )

cc_toolchain_config = rule(
    implementation = _impl,
    attrs = {},
    provides = [CcToolchainConfigInfo],
)
```

How can I expand "relative/clang/include" to a real path?

Answer (score 1):

There's a special syntax for doing this. It looks like `"%package(@your_toolchain//relative/clang/include)%"`, with `@your_toolchain` replaced with your repository's name

Those directives get expanded when generating compiler command lines. I'm not aware of any documentation besides [the source](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/6d448136d13ddab92da8bb29ea6e8387821369d9:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/CcToolchainProviderHelper.java;l=309-329).

Comment: I'm trying to use this with Bazel 5.3.2 and it doesn't seem to work. I'm adding `%package(@hermetic_toolchain_clang15//lib/clang/15.0.7/include)%` to `cxx_builtin_include_directories` and it seems to have no effect. What is even more suspect is that if I replace `@hermetic_toolchain_clang15` with non-existent package name, Bazel doesn't complain.